# Docker On Mac - OCI runtime create failed: mkdir permission denied

Tags: macos, docker

When trying to run my docker file. I get the following error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/Users/hkatyal/go/src/github.com/purser/bin/amd64\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c144a9b95f53811b456c7a4e84064bf4231a2a94afcf2c77b8c6d031c3f4bf87/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c144a9b95f53811b456c7a4e84064bf4231a2a94afcf2c77b8c6d031c3f4bf87/merged/go/bin/linux_amd64\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c144a9b95f53811b456c7a4e84064bf4231a2a94afcf2c77b8c6d031c3f4bf87/merged/go/bin/linux_amd64: permission denied\\\"\"": unknown.
```

My Docker Cmd is as follows:

```
@docker run                                                            \
    -ti                                                                \
    -u $$(id -u):$$(id -g)                                             \
    -v $$(pwd)/.go:/go:$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)                            \
    -v $$(pwd)/$(BUILD):/go/src/$(PRO)/$(BUILD):$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)   \
    -v $$(pwd)/$(CMD):/go/src/$(PRO)/$(CMD):$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)                     \
    -v $$(pwd)/$(PKG):/go/src/$(PRO)/$(PKG):$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)                     \
    -v $$(pwd)/$(DEP):/go/src/$(PRO)/$(DEP):$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)                     \
    -v $$(pwd)/bin/$(ARCH):/go/bin:$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)                \
    -v $$(pwd)/bin/$(ARCH):/go/bin/linux_$(ARCH):$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)  \
    -v $$(pwd)/.go/std/$(ARCH):/usr/local/go/pkg/linux_$(ARCH)_static:$(DOCKER_MOUNT_MODE)  \
    -w /go/src                                                 \
    golang:1.11                                                     \
    /bin/sh -c "                                                       \
        ARCH=$(ARCH)                                                   \
        VERSION=$(VERSION)                                             \
        PKG=$(PKG)                                                     \
        ./$(PRO)/$(BUILD)/build.sh                                               \
    "
```

This issue is coming in Mac working fine for Linux. Do I need to change some settings?

Environment Details as follows:

```
macOS Version: 10.13.6
```

Docker Version:

```
$  docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.0
  API version:       1.39
  Go version:        go1.10.4
  Git commit:        4d60db4
  Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:47:43 2018
  OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
  Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
 Version:          18.09.0
 API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:       go1.10.4
 Git commit:       4d60db4
 Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:55:00 2018
 OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
 Experimental:     true
```

Comment: That looks like a Makefile fragment, not a Dockerfile.  Can you include the complete Makefile, including any relevant environment variables, and trim it down to a [mcve]?  (Glancing at that I'd guess trying to have overlapping mounts in `/go/bin` is a problem, and that this setup would be much easier if it _was_ written as a Dockerfile.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, Here's the complete file - https://github.com/vmware/purser/blob/master/.make/Makefile.deploy.controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Mac machine isn't a real Docker host and Docker on Mac runs on the VM and the Docker volumes are not in the path.

[Details here](https://timonweb.com/posts/getting-path-and-accessing-persistent-volumes-in-docker-for-mac/).